# What is the nutritional profile of A&W plant-based nuggets?

Tags: nutrition, meat-substitutes, restaurant, canada

*<sub>I know that nutrition and fast food are usually opposite concepts, but I'm still curious...</sub>*

A&W Canada recently [added](https://www.globenewswire.com/news-release/2021/08/04/2274494/0/en/Beyond-Meat-Expands-Partnership-With-A-W-Canada-To-Launch-Plant-Based-Chicken-Nuggets-Nationwide-for-a-Limited-Time-Starting-August-9.html) plant-based chicken nuggets to their menu (again!). I'm curious about their nutritional profile, especially as compared to regular chicken nuggets, but I'm having a hard time finding any detailed information. So far, this is all I can find:

> 18 grams of plant-based protein per six pieces [[1](https://www.globenewswire.com/news-release/2021/08/04/2274494/0/en/Beyond-Meat-Expands-Partnership-With-A-W-Canada-To-Launch-Plant-Based-Chicken-Nuggets-Nationwide-for-a-Limited-Time-Starting-August-9.html)][[2](https://www.meatpoultry.com/articles/25321-beyond-meat-a-and-w-canada-partner-on-chicken-nugget-alternative)]

Is that considered a "complete" protein? And what about the other macronutrients like fat and carbohydrates? I'm especially interested in a comparison between traditional chicken nuggets and these new plant-based nuggets.

I've tried looking at the [Beyond Meat page on the A&W website](https://web.aw.ca/en/our-values/our-food/beyondmeat) but it doesn't mention the nuggets at all. And I found this link to a page on their website about plant-based nuggets but [it's just a blank page](https://web.aw.ca/en/our-values/our-food/plant-based-nuggets).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nutritional info is at https://web.aw.ca/en/our-menu/chicken/beyond-meat-nuggets

```
Calories     300
Fat          15.6 g
Protein      18   g
Serving Size 120  g

Nutrition Contents
    Sugar          1.44 g
    Carbohydrates  22   g
    Trans Fat      0.18 g
    Saturated Fat  2.40 g
    Cholesterol    0    mg
    Fibre          5    g
    Sodium         518  mg


% of Daily Value
    Calcium   28 %
    Iron      5  %
    Vitamin A 36 %
    Vitamin C 1  %
```

Answer (score 2):

I found [a post on foodgressing.com](https://foodgressing.com/beyond-meat-nuggets-aw-canada/) that provides the nutrition details, then I used [Cronometer.com](https://cronometer.com/) to generate a nutrition label.

[image: American nutrition label, as generated by Cronometer]

---

### Nutrition Label (as text)

For people who can't see the image, here's the nutrition label as plain text.

**Beyond Meat 10 pieces** (without dipping sauce)

Serving size: 200 g

```
Calories: 500 calories  
Fat:                  26.0 g
  Saturated Fat:       4.0 g
  Trans Fat:           0.3 g
Cholesterol:           0.0 mg
Sodium:              864.0 mg
Total Carbohydrate:   37.0 g
  Sugar:               2.4 g
  Fibre:               8.0 g
Protein:              30.0 g

Calcium:    46% of Daily Value
Iron:       8% of Daily Value
Vitamin A:  60% of Daily Value
Vitamin C:  2% of Daily Value
```

### Cronometer Analysis

Analysis with [cronometer](https://cronometer.com/) shows that the energy (calories) in these plant-based nuggets comes 47% from fat, 24% from protein, and 30% from carbohydrates.

[image]

### Comparison with Chicken Nuggets

Compared to generic chicken nuggets (NCCDB Food #462860), the A&W plant-based nuggets have...

- the same calories/energy
- **less** fat
- **more** protein
- **more** carbohydrate
- the same saturated fat